# Truffle test failed with "invalid opcode"

Tags: javascript, solidity, truffle

I am writing a unit test for my smart contract using truffle and when I run the test using "truffle test" the test failed with this error "Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode".

smart contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.3;

contract owned {
    address public owner;

    /* Initialise contract creator as owner */
    function owned() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    /* Function to dictate that only the designated owner can call a function */
      modifier onlyOwner {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    /* Transfer ownership of this contract to someone else */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner() {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

/*
 * @title AsnScRegistry
 *  Open Vote Network
 *  A self-talling protocol that supports voter privacy.
 *
 *  Author: Shahrul Sharudin
 */
contract AsnScRegistry is owned{
  struct IPAddress {
    uint128 ip;
    uint8 mask;
    }

  struct MemberAddresses {
    address contractAddress;
    address walletAddress;
    uint index;
  }

  mapping (uint => IPAddress[]) managedIps;
  mapping (uint => MemberAddresses) ethAddresses;

  uint[] private registeredAsn;

  function getManagedIpByAsn(uint _asn) view public returns (uint128[] _ip, uint8[] _mask){
    IPAddress[] memory addresses = managedIps[_asn];
    uint128[] memory ips = new uint128[](addresses.length);
    uint8[] memory mask = new uint8[](addresses.length);

    for (uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
            ips[i] = addresses[i].ip;
            mask[i] = addresses[i].mask;
        }
    return (ips, mask);
  }

  function getMemberAddressesByAsn(uint _asn) view public returns (address _contractAddress, address _walletAddress){
    MemberAddresses memory memberAddresses = ethAddresses[_asn];
    return (memberAddresses.contractAddress, memberAddresses.walletAddress);
  }

  function addMember(uint _asn, uint128[] _ip, uint8[] _mask, address _contractAddress, address _walletAddress) public {
    MemberAddresses memory member = ethAddresses[_asn];
    //throw error if member already exist
    assert(member.contractAddress != 0);
    for(uint i=0; i<_ip.length; i++){
      managedIps[_asn].push(IPAddress({ip:_ip[i], mask:_mask[i]}));
    }
    uint idx = registeredAsn.push(_asn)-1;
    ethAddresses[_asn] = MemberAddresses({contractAddress:_contractAddress, walletAddress:_walletAddress, index:idx});
  }

  function removeMember(uint _asn) public returns (uint[] _registeredAsn){
    //uint memory index = ethAddresses[_asn].index;

    if (ethAddresses[_asn].index >= registeredAsn.length) return;

    for (uint i = ethAddresses[_asn].index; i<registeredAsn.length - 1; i++){
      registeredAsn[i] = registeredAsn[i+1];
    }
        registeredAsn.length--;
        delete managedIps[_asn];
        delete ethAddresses[_asn];

        return registeredAsn;
  }

  function getTotalMembers() view public returns (uint _totalMembers) {
    return (registeredAsn.length);
  }

  function getRegisteredAsn() view public returns (uint[] _asn){
    return (registeredAsn);
  }

}
```

javascript unit test:

```
const AsnScRegistry = artifacts.require('./AsnScRegistry.sol')
const assert = require('assert')

const ip = [3524503734,3232235776];
const mask = [255,255];
const contractAddress = '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567891';
const walletAddress = '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567891';
const asn = 123;

let registryInstance;

contract("AsnScRegistry", accounts => {
  it("Should add a new member", () =>
    AsnScRegistry.deployed()
    .then(instance => {
      registryInstance = instance;
      return instance.addMember(asn, ip, mask, contractAddress, walletAddress);
    })
    .then(() => registryInstance.getTotalMembers())
    .then(total => assert.equal(total.toNumber(), 1, "xxxxx"))
  );
});
```

the full source is available here: https://github.com/shaza4061/electioncommissioner

I expect the addMember() function to store the information in the smart contract and getTotalMembers() to return the number of record in registeredAsn[] array and the assertion in the unit test to pass.

Comment: The solidity code that you provided does not compile with `solidity 0.4.3`. Which `version` are you using?

Comment: I am using version ```0.4.21```

Comment: You wrote `assert(member.contractAddress != 0);`, but you probably meant `assert(member.contractAddress == 0);`.

Comment: Yes, smartx is correct. the assert condition is wrong. changing the condition solve my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following error message:

```
 "Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode"
```

indicates a failed **assert** statement in solidity.

In your code, you have an **assert** which causes this error.

```
 //throw error if member already exist
    assert(member.contractAddress != 0);
```

[Here](https://trufflesuite.com/guides/debugging-a-smart-contract/) is a manual for Solidity Smart contract debugging using Truffle.